# Boolean expression in column indexer (Pandas) 'is' operator not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, indexing

When I use:

```
df = data2analyse.loc[data2analyse.bool_var1 | data2analyse.bool_var2 |
                          data2analyse.bool_var3, 'some column']
```

works properly. But if I use

```
df = data2analyse.loc[data2analyse.bool_var1 is True | data2analyse.bool_var2 is True |
                          data2analyse.bool_var3 is True, 'some column']
```

raises a `KeyError: False` exception. Also, if I use

```
df = data2analyse.loc[data2analyse.bool_var1 == True | data2analyse.bool_var2 == True |
                              data2analyse.bool_var3 == True, 'some column']
```

raises: `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

What's the difference between theses notations within the context of `.loc`? What is the reason of the errors?

Comment: put your predicates into `(...)` like: `(data2analyse.bool_var1 == True) | (data2analyse.bool_var2 == True) | (data2analyse.bool_var3 == True)`

Comment: @MaxU Thank you. You are right, but if I use `var is True` doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you shouldn't use `is` operator in this case, because `is` tells you whether it's the same object, i.e. whether `id()` of both objects are equal.

```
In [43]: df
Out[43]:
       a      b      c
0  False  False  False
1   True   True   True
2   True  False  False
3  False   True  False
4   True  False  False

In [44]: id(True)
Out[44]: 497422000

In [45]: id(False)
Out[45]: 497422032

In [46]: id(df.a)
Out[46]: 150038344

In [47]: df.a is True
Out[47]: False

In [48]: df.a is False
Out[48]: False

In [49]: df.a == False
Out[49]:
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
Name: a, dtype: bool
```

Operators like (`==`,`!=`, etc.) are overwritten for pandas objects - that's why the last statement works properly

So you should do it this way:

```
In [50]: df.a | df.b | df.c
Out[50]:
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
dtype: bool

In [51]: (df.a == True) | (df.b == True) | (df.c == True)
Out[51]:
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
dtype: bool
```

alternatively you can do this (as an alternative for: `df.a | df.b | df.c`):

```
In [55]: df.any(axis=1)
Out[55]:
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
dtype: bool
```

or this (as an alternative for: `df.a & df.b & df.c`):

```
In [56]: df.all(axis=1)
Out[56]:
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Great response. I have another question: Why do I have to enclose the predicator with parenthesis when I use the ´==´ operator?

Comment: @JuanDavid: The [operator precedence table](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) shows that `|` binds more tightly than `==`. Therefore, without the parentheses `df.a == True | df.b == True` would be evaluated as `df.a == (True | df.b) == True`.

Comment: @unutbu, thank you! It's very clear and neat explanation!